# Is there a way to cross-reference symbols across multiple translation units using libtooling?

Tags: c++, clang, libclang, libtooling

I have a Lib and multiple Applications. I want to gather usage statistics about function calls to Lib's API from Apps. 
Basically my current process is:

- Parse the Lib for all functions/methods
- Output the info in a formatted way
- Use that output to gather stats from the Apps.

I'm currently using the libclang API that offers [cross-referencing](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__XREF.html) in the form of USRs so I'm building an index of functions and use that when parsing the Apps. The problem is that this API is limited and that's why I want to move to Libtooling.

I've looked through libtooling's API but I haven't been able to find anything similar. So my question is what would be the best way to achieve that "cross-referencing" using Libtooling.

An example would be:

```
> lib.h

 class Foo {
 public:
       void bar();
 };


> app.cpp

#include "lib.h"

int main(void) {
    Foo f;
    f.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

And expected output would be a json file:

```
{
  "name": "bar",
  "location": { "file": "lib.h", "line": 5},
  "references": [{"file": "app.cpp", "line": 8}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you are using `clang_getCursorUSR` from libclang
(the C API) and want an equivalent for libtooling (the C++ API).

`clang_getCursorUSR` is defined in
[`CIndexUSRs.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/tools/libclang/CIndexUSRs.cpp).
For [`Decl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Decl.html)
objects (which is probably the main use case), it calls
[`clang::index::generateUSRForDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/USRGeneration_8h.html).

So to do likewise, assuming you have a `clang::Decl *decl` from
somewhere, do something like:

```
  llvm::SmallVector<char, 80> vec;
  clang::index::generateUSRForDecl(decl, vec);
  string usr(vec.data(), vec.size());
  cout << "USR: " << usr << "\n";
```

The resulting USR string is claimed to be stable across translation
units.  It appears to be something like a portable version of a
[mangled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).  An example
is `c:@S@ID@F@ID#&1$@S@ID#`, which is the copy constructor for a class
called `ID`.